# IONIC 2 Android back button handler

Tags: angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, angular

Allright, so i googled it. Found a lot of answers but nothing worked for me.

I am using IONIC 2 and Angular 2. I am able to override the 'backbutton' event with

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', backButtonCallBack, false);
```

in the call back i did a console.log('test'); and i could see it in the console.

But the event.preventDefault() method doesnt work for me.

I'm kinda stucked right now lol

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: what's the question again?

Comment: @AngJobs I didn't know that it wasn't clear. Sorry for that. But i just need to know why my preventDefault() doesn't work. I'm trying to disable the Android backbutton anywhere in my app.

Comment: Maybe it's an ionic bug

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3791